API call in localhost angular micro frontend
I have angular micro-frontend setup locally. I need to make an API call. I have tried setting up both proxy.conf.js and proxy.conf.json but the proxy seems to be getting bypassed. I cannot use ng server --proxy-config because when I'm using either native federation or module federation, this is not allowed. But trying to configure the proxy into angular.json does not work either. I have tried looking around for the resources that address this problem I can't seem to find them. Does anyone know how to solve the CORS problem when using angular microfrontends?
